# how to set image on text view

Tags: android

I am new to android and in my app I need a text view ,inside that text view I want to display an image at first and text as following to that Image.also I do set background I image for that text.Hope somebody will help.

Comment: You can use ImageView for that.

Answer (score 2):

//you can use `drawableLeft, drawableRight, drawableTop, drawableBottom` attributes to draw image

```
<TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:text="@string/edit" 
        android:background="@drawable/btn_selector"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_cab_done_holo_dark"
/>
```

[Ref here:](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/button.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use `android:drawableLeft` attribute in your `TextView` tag in xml.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TextView and Imageview for this.

Comment: Actually my task is to design a chat screen,In each raw there should be an image and message he enters.